# How do I stop Magento from inserting <br> tags automatically in product descriptions?

Tags: magento

Whenever you want to add some custom html to product descriptions in Magento you start getting **br** tags on the frontend that seem to come out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Magento function that's causing this, in order to disable it go to either:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml

OR

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

The actual file to be modified depends on your version of Magento.
You should find a reference to `nl2br` in the correct file.

1. Copy this file in your custom template ***DO NOT MODIFY CORE FILES***
   (they will come back to bite you).
2. Remove '`nl2br`'
3. Clear cache